# Update OR Change the entire column values if new entry happens

Tags: php, database

```
id  name    amt    %
1    A     3000   100%
2    B     1500   45%
```

Now I have a sum of `SUM(amount)*A(amount)/100`, I got 100% as A's Contribution
Now if we have another partner entering the second value it will count the percent with new total value, but i want that the old value i.e 100% should also get recalculated because the total in increased now.Like wise i have many rows.every time it should be calculated with new total.

i got stuck here, working with php.

**CODE:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) AS val_sum FROM member_detail") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['val_sum']; 
$sumall = $sum+$amount; 
//echo ($sumall); 
$avg = $amount/$sumall*100; 
$sql = "insert into investment (mem_name,p_amount,percentage) values ('$name','$amount','$avg')"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
$obj->insert("member_detail",$_POST); 
$msg = "Member added Successfully";
```

Comment: Could you  show  the respective code?

Comment: $result =  mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) AS val_sum FROM member_detail")or die(mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 $sum = $row['val_sum'];
 $sumall = $sum+$amount;
 //echo ($sumall);
 $avg = $amount/$sumall*100;
 
 $sql = "insert into investment (mem_name,p_amount,percentage) values ('$name','$amount','$avg')";
 $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 
 $obj->insert("member_detail",$_POST);
 $msg = "Member added Successfully";

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php
$obj->insert("member_detail",$_POST); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) AS val_sum FROM member_detail")or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['val_sum'];

$sql = "insert into investment (mem_name,p_amount,percentage) values ('$name','$amount',0)"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id AS val_sum FROM member_detail")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$sumall = $row['val_sum']; 
$avg = $amount/$sumall*100; 
$sql = "update investment set percentage='$avg' where id=".$row['id']; 
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
}
$msg = "Member added Successfully";
```